# UTM tracking across sub-domains

Tags: google-analytics, utm

I have a main website (e.g. mybrand.com ) with static pages mostly developed on Wix.com and I have a full application hosted on AWS on a sub-domain, e.g. app..com.

For tracking the traffic coming from different social media channels, we are building UTMs. My understanding is that the UTM tracking doesn't work when you hop between the sub-domains.   Can you please suggest some clever options?

One option for us is to re-do the Wix website in WordPress and host WordPress ourselves on AWS next to our WebApp to completely avoid the domain hoping.   But if we have a more elegant solution while keeping the Website, it would be preferred.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a simple parameter in querystring (i.e. *subdomain.com/page?from=domain1*) then in Analytics count unique page with that parameter in the URL.